# How to create a function for desktop only?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, mousemove

I have an event listener that is currently being triggered on mousemove. However i want this to only be applied to desktop and not mobile.

And vice versa, for my own reference how would I apply it to mobile only if I wanted to?

Here is my function wrapped around an if statement that if the innerWidth is more than 1000, to trigger add the event listener on mousemove. however I still see it being applied to mobile.

```
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(inactiveUser, 10000));
    }
```

If it's helpful, I am triggering an action event being sent to a tool we use for analytics and campaigns called Evergage. The function is below, along with a console log that I added:

```
    const inactiveUser = () => {
        console.log("mouse move on desktop only");
        sendEvent({
            action: "Inactive Checkout",
        });
    };
```

Comment: Invert your strategy. The event handler runs for all screen sizes, but you only take action inside it for larger screens.